# How to split dataframe by row names using 'for' function?

Tags: for-loop, split, sapply

`1. My dataframe has a 2850 variables. So I show you example of rownames in my dataframe.

| K_1| K_1_A || K_1_B |...|K_1_AC|K_2|K_2_A|K_2_B|K_2_C|...|K_2_AC|...|K_95|K_95_A |...|K_95_AC|

The dataframe have a rownames from K_1 to K_95AC. Therefore total of variables are 95*30 = 2850.

2. I want to split the dataframe by number of rownames. For exmaple,

#L1

|K_1| K_1_A || K_1_B |...|K_1_AC|

#L2

|K_2|K_2_A|K_2_B|K_2_C|...|K_2_AC|

.
.
.

#L95

|K_95|K_95_A |...|K_95_AC|

To avoid the repeated work(from 1 to 95), I tried to use 'for' function like below I wrote.

ver 1.

```
for (i in 1:95) {
  sapply(c("K_i", "K_i_A", "K_i_B", "K_i_C", "K_i_D", 
           "K_i_E", "K_i_F", "K_i_G", "K_i_H", "K_i_I",
           "K_i_J", "K_i_K", "K_i_L", "K_i_M", "K_i_N",
           "K_i_O", "K_i_P", "K_i_Q", "K_i_R", "K_i_S",
           "K_i_T", "K_i_U", "K_i_V", "K_i_W", "K_i_X",
           "K_i_Y", "K_i_Z", "K_i_AA", "K_i_AB", "K_i_AC"), 
         function(x) meaning[startswWith(names(meaning),x)] simplify = FALSE}
```

or

ver 2.

```
group_names <- paste0("L", 1:95)
num_rownames_per_group <- 30

split_df_list <- split(meaning, rep(group_names, each = num_rownames_per_group))

for(i in seq_along(split_df_list)){
  group_names <- names(split_df_list)[i]
  print(paste("#", group_names))`your text`
  print(split_df_list[[i]])
  cat("\n")
}
```

But it does not work.
What should I do?

`

Comment: When you write _rownames_, do you mean row names, or rather column names?

Answer (score 0):

```
list_count <- 95
lists <- list() 
column_exists <- function(col_name) {
  col_name %in% colnames(meaning)
} 

for (i in 1:list_count) {
  list_name <- paste0("List", i)
  lists[[list_name]] <- list()  
  
  for (col_name in colnames(meaning)) {
    pattern <- paste0("^K_", i, "(_[A-Z]+)?$") 
    if (grepl(pattern, col_name) && column_exists(col_name)) {
      lists[[list_name]][[col_name]] <- meaning[[col_name]]
    }
  }
} 



data_frame_list <- lapply(1:95, function(i) {
  do.call(data.frame, lists[[paste0("List", i)]])
})

icc_results <- lapply(data_frame_list, function(df) {
  icc(df, model = "twoway", type = "consistency", unit = "average")
}
  )
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).